# extract latest tag from source branch in SVN with PHP

Tags: php, svn, version-control, php-5.3

I have two branches in my application:

- 01
- 02

When I tag from these branches for a code release I create a tag called `01.01`, for example.

Is there a way to extract the latest tag from subversion or the revision graph? Is it possible to have a PHP script and pass it the branch URL and it can parse the revision graph or something similar to give me the latest tag?

Comment: @ColeJohnson SmartSVN is an application. I am looking to extract data from the SVN server from _PHP_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar.  I keep this structure:
    \repo-base
       \trunk
       \branches
       \releases

The only thing the releases folder gets it copies (tags) of \trunk on when ready to release.  I then automate deploying it by first getting the latest release tag with:

```
svn log -l 1 -v <url to release folder>
```

I then use a regex to parse out the line I need, Which will always be the latest release.  You can use a svn PHP library, or just exec commands in your php script.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like `exec('svn log -l 1 -v <url to release folder>');`?

Comment: @crmpicco Yes, but i wrap the svn calls and grepping and such in a shell script that returns exactly what i want-- the name of the copy/tag.  I then exec that script.

Comment: This command does work, so thanks. However, it doesn't get around the issue of having two branches (say 01 and 02 for talking sakes). It is becoming apparent that it's not necessarily simple to extract the most recent tag from each branch, unless I do it in code?